# RecyclerView.Adapter custom filter exception

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a custom RecyclerView.Adapter class where I implemented a Filterable and used the interface method override like so:

```
private MyFilter myFilter = new MyFilter(); // Class implemented below
```

and also implemented the:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return myFilter;
}
```

This is MyFilter class implementation:

```
    public class MyFilter extends Filter {


        @Override
        protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults filterResult = new FilterResults();

            // If the constraint is 0 return the original data
            if(constraint.length() == 0) {

                filterResult.values = data;
                filterResult.count = data.size();
                return filterResult;

            }

            // Method local properties used to assemble the filtered list
            //String folderName;
            //String cardsNumber;
            //String rowId;
            String tempConstraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            // Iterate through the original data array
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

                // Get the folder name from the data array
//                folderName = data.get(i).familyName;
//                cardsNumber = data.get(i).numOfCards;
//                rowId = data.get(i).folderRowId;

                // Check to see if the constraint variable corresponds to the folder name or to the
                // number of cards belonging to this particular folder
                if(data.get(i).familyName.toString().toLowerCase().contains(tempConstraint)) {

                    tempFolderRow = new FolderRow();

                    tempFolderRow.familyName = data.get(i).familyName;
                    tempFolderRow.numOfCards = data.get(i).numOfCards;
                    tempFolderRow.folderRowId = data.get(i).folderRowId;

                    // Add this object to the updated filtered list
                    filteredNames.add(data.get(i));

                }
            }

            // Assign the new list to the object filterResult for return
            filterResult.values = filteredNames;
            filterResult.count = filteredNames.size();

            return filterResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {

            if(results.values != null) {

                Log.e("Values: ", results.values.toString());
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Next, in my activity I have my editText widget implemented like this:

```
searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Filter the folder adapter
            mAdapterFolder.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
```

Debugging my Filter class (see code above), when it reaches the:

```
filteredNames.add(data.get(i)); // filteredNames is a List<FolderRow> obj
```

it returns an exception that looks like this:

> 03-08 17:06:36.085  27853-27984/com.name.cardbox W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
>       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>               at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
>               at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
>               at com.birsan.cardbox.FolderAdapter$MyFilter.performFiltering(FolderAdapter.java:288)
>               at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

One more thing, if I comment out the line where the exception happens, (filteredNames.add(data.get(i));) the previous for loop works fine, so I think this is where the problem is. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems like Filters don't work well with List<> objects. I changed:

> filteredNames

from being a

> List < FolderRow >

object to

> ArrayList < FolderRow >

. That got it working.